# SQL using partition across tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I have following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `T1` (
    `user`,
    `str_to_match`,
    `x` ,
    `y` 
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `T2` (
    `user`,
    `ID`,
    `str_to_match`,
    `a`,
    `b` 
);
```

Following values are inserted into two tables:

```
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('U1','123', 23, 'YVAL');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('U2','123', 21, 'YVAL1');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('U2','121', 27, 'YVAL2');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('U1','123', 28, 'YVAL3');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('U1','456', 30, 'YVAL4');

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('U1', 1, '123', 'AVAL', 'BVAL');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('U1', 2, '123', 'AVAL1', 'BVAL1');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('U2', 3, '123', 'AVAL2', 'BVAL2');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('U2', 4, '121', 'AVAL3', 'BVAL3');
```

I am trying for the below output

```
T1.user, T1.str_to_match, SUM(T1.x), COUNT(T1.x), T2.ID, T2.a, T2.b
U1, '123', 51, 2, 1, 'AVAL', 'BVAL'
U1, '123', 51, 2, 2, 'AVAL1', 'BVAL1'
U2, '123', 21, 1, 3, 'AVAL2', 'BVAL2'
U2, '121', 27, 1, 4, 'AVAL3', 'BVAL3'
```

I have used over partition by on table T1 for cols user and str_to_match and am able to get aggregation, **but unable to join this with table T2 to get complete desired output.** Aggregation has to be performed only if there is a match for str_to_match col in table T1 and T2 for the same user.

Here is my current query which works on table T1

```
SELECT SUM(x) OVER (PARTITION BY user, str_to_match), 
COUNT(x)  OVER (PARTITION BY user, str_to_match), 
str_to_match, 
user from T1
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Product specific issue.)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? the create table looks like MySQL but that doesn't support window functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will give you the exact result that are expecting above :

```
select distinct abc.[User], abc.str_to_match, abc.sumval,
abc.countval,T2.ID, T2.a, T2.b
from
(select T1.[user],T1.str_to_match, SUM(T1.x) as sumval, COUNT(T1.x) as countval from T1 
group by T1.[user],T1.str_to_match) abc
inner join t2 on t2.[user] = abc.[user] and t2.str_to_match = abc.str_to_match;
```

Please find the attached screenshot links for query and output below :

[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYFUi.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMeBa.png)

Comment: perfect. works like a charm. would it be possible for you to explain your approach as well.
Accepting your answer.

Comment: Some times we go to a different approach that actually does not have a solution. Same in your query, yo do not have to use "partition". It can be done simply by "GroupBy"  . So in my first subquery, I have selected whatever that you were looking from table first and then did a inner join with second table based on condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
Below query will give you the expected output

select distinct t.str_to_match,t.[user],total,cnt
,t2.id,t2.a,t2.b 
from (SELECT SUM(x) OVER (PARTITION BY [user], str_to_match) total, 
COUNT(x)  OVER (PARTITION BY [user], str_to_match) cnt, 
str_to_match, 
[user] from @T1 ) as t
join @T2 t2 on t.str_to_match = t2.str_to_match and t.[user] = t2.[user]
order by t.[user],id
```

Comment: well, str_to_match should not be distinct. As for same user, it can have different values for cols t2.a, t2.b in the same row. example:
U1, '123', 51, 2, 1, 'AVAL', 'BVAL'
U1, '123', 51, 2, 2, 'AVAL1', 'BVAL1'

Comment: I have done distinct because it is doing cross join as there is same data in both tables .example U1,'123'

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you? (this is Standard SQL in BigQuery)

```
with T1 as(
select 'U1' as user, '123' as str_to_match, 23 as x, 'YVAL' as y union all
select 'U2' as user, '123' as str_to_match, 21 as x, 'YVAL1' as y union all
select 'U2' as user, '121' as str_to_match, 27 as x, 'YVAL2' as y union all
select 'U1' as user, '123' as str_to_match, 28 as x, 'YVAL3' as y union all
select 'U1' as user, '456' as str_to_match, 30 as x, 'YVAL4' as y
),
T2 as(
select 'U1' as user, 1 as ID, '123' as str_to_match, 'AVAL' as a, 'BVAL' as b union all
select 'U1' as user, 2 as ID, '123' as str_to_match, 'AVAL1' as a, 'BVAL1' as b union all
select 'U2' as user, 3 as ID, '123' as str_to_match, 'AVAL2' as a, 'BVAL2' as b union all
select 'U2' as user, 4 as ID, '121' as str_to_match, 'AVAL3' as a, 'BVAL3' as b
)


select 
T1.user user, T1.str_to_match str_to_match, sum(T1.x) sum_x, count(T1.x) count_x, T2.ID ID, T2.a a, T2.b b
from T1
join T2
on T1.user = T2.user and T1.str_to_match = T2.str_to_match
group by 
user, str_to_match, ID, a, b
order by user, id
```

I'm not sure if I understood correctly your question but for what I could see in your desired output you want to first distinguish between the users IDs values and then run the summations and counts operation, which could be done by first joining **T1** with **T2**.

Comment: sorry but hardcoding str_to_match won't help, as rows in table are close to million.

Answer (score 1):

not totally clear but I think LEFT JOIN with regular aggregation is the way to go (no window functions applicable here)

```
#standardSQL
WITH T1 AS (
  SELECT 'U1' AS user, '123' AS str_to_match, 23 AS x,  'YVAL' AS y UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U2' AS user, '123' AS str_to_match, 21 AS x, 'YVAL1' AS y UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U2' AS user, '121' AS str_to_match, 27 AS x, 'YVAL2' AS y UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U1' AS user, '123' AS str_to_match, 28 AS x, 'YVAL3' AS y UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U1' AS user, '456' AS str_to_match, 30 AS x, 'YVAL4' AS y
),
T2 AS (
  SELECT 'U1' AS user, 1 AS ID, '123' AS str_to_match,  'AVAL' AS a,  'BVAL' AS b UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U1' AS user, 2 AS ID, '123' AS str_to_match, 'AVAL1' AS a, 'BVAL1' AS b UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U2' AS user, 3 AS ID, '123' AS str_to_match, 'AVAL2' AS a, 'BVAL2' AS b UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U2' AS user, 4 AS ID, '121' AS str_to_match, 'AVAL3' AS a, 'BVAL3' AS b
)
SELECT 
  T2.user AS user, 
  T2.str_to_match AS str_to_match, 
  T2.ID AS ID, 
  T2.a AS a, 
  T2.b AS b,
  SUM(T1.x) AS sum_x, 
  COUNT(T1.x) AS count_x
FROM T2 LEFT JOIN T1 
ON T1.user = T2.user AND T1.str_to_match = T2.str_to_match
GROUP BY user, str_to_match, ID, a, b
```